# How to use or typing in TypeScript generics

Tags: typescript

I was trying to give either one a typing match for the generic method.
In the example below, I have a predefined method **identify** that accepts generic typing. Now I want to define OR typing to identify, which should accept either person or location.

The identity method comes from a third-party library that I cannot modify.
When I tried below scenario, it returned an error

```
Argument of type '{ city: string; country: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Person | Location'.
  Type '{ city: string; country: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Location': ancestorOrigins, hash, host, hostname, and 9 more.
```

```
function identity<Type>(arg: Type): Type {
  return arg;
}

interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface Location {
  city: string;
  country: string;
}

identity<Person | Location>({city: 'SA', country: 'USA'})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what is happening here is that `Location` is colliding/merging with the global `Location` type from `lib.dom.d.ts`

If you give it another name, eg: `MyLocation` it should work fine.

Another option is to disable the `lib.dom.d.ts` types if you're not in a web browser environment (eg: you're writing a NodeJS application) - I'd recommend using a base configuration from https://github.com/tsconfig/bases for NodeJS projects if so.